# Webscraping challenges in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to webscrape this [link](https://www.bis.org/cbspeeches/index.htm?m=1123) in Python. The ideal output is a dataframe with 4 columns: date, author, title and text. So far, I got down to author, title and date in the following way:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

payload = 'from=&till=&objid=cbspeeches&page=&paging_length=10&sort_list=date_desc&theme=cbspeeches&ml=false&mlurl=&emptylisttext='
url= 'https://www.bis.org/doclist/cbspeeches.htm'
headers= {
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
    }

req=requests.post(url,headers=headers,data=payload)
print(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "lxml")
data=[]
for card in soup.select('.documentList tbody tr'):
    date = card.select('.item_date')
    title = card.select_one('.title a').get_text()
    author = card.select_one('.authorlnk.dashed').get_text().strip()
    data.append({
        'date': date,
        'title':title,
        'author':author
        })

print(data)
```

Now, I find hard to extract the text for each of the 10 links in the page. I am doing the following:

```
data = []

for link in soup.select('.documentList tbody tr'):
    r = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(f"https://www.bis.org{link['href']}").content,features="lxml")    
     data.append({
        'Text': ''.join([str(e) for e in r.select('p')])})
```

However, I am not getting any good results around that code.

Can anyone help me with that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close to your goal, simply handle the requests to the texts in your for loop:

```
for card in soup.select('.documentList tbody tr'):
    r = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(f"https://www.bis.org{card.a.get('href')}").content)
    data.append({
        'date': card.select_one('.item_date').get_text(strip=True),
        'title': card.select_one('.title a').get_text(strip=True),
        'author': card.select_one('.authorlnk.dashed').get_text(strip=True),
        'url': f"https://www.bis.org{card.a.get('href')}",
        'text': r.select_one('#cmsContent').get_text('\n\n', strip=True)
        })
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests

payload = 'from=&till=&objid=cbspeeches&page=&paging_length=10&sort_list=date_desc&theme=cbspeeches&ml=false&mlurl=&emptylisttext='
url= 'https://www.bis.org/doclist/cbspeeches.htm'
headers= {
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
    }

req=requests.post(url,headers=headers,data=payload)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "lxml")
data=[]
for card in soup.select('.documentList tbody tr'):
    r = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(f"https://www.bis.org{card.a.get('href')}").content)
    data.append({
        'date': card.select_one('.item_date').get_text(strip=True),
        'title': card.select_one('.title a').get_text(strip=True),
        'author': card.select_one('.authorlnk.dashed').get_text(strip=True),
        'url': f"https://www.bis.org{card.a.get('href')}",
        'text': r.select_one('#cmsContent').get_text('\n\n', strip=True)
        })

pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.get_text()` with `separator=` parameter. For example:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


api_url = "https://www.bis.org/doclist/cbspeeches.htm"

payload = {
    "from": "",
    "till": "",
    "objid": "cbspeeches",
    "page": "1",
    "paging_length": "25",
    "sort_list": "date_desc",
    "theme": "cbspeeches",
    "ml": "false",
    "mlurl": "",
    "emptylisttext": "",
}


all_data = []
for payload["page"] in range(1, 3):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(
        requests.post(api_url, data=payload).content, "html.parser"
    )

    for row in soup.select(".item"):
        date = row.select_one(".item_date").get_text(strip=True)
        author = row.select_one(".authorlnk").get_text(strip=True)
        title = row.a.get_text(strip=True)
        text = row.select_one(".info").get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")

        all_data.append((date, author, title, text))

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data, columns=["Date", "Author", "Title", "Text"])
print(df.head(5).to_markdown(index=False))
```

Prints:

| Date | Author | Title | Text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 08 Jul 2022 | Lael Brainard | Lael Brainard: Crypto-assets and decentralized finance through a financial stability lens | Speech by Ms Lael Brainard, Member of the Board of Governors of the Federal Reserve System, at the Bank of England Conference, London , 8 July 2022. by Lael Brainard |
| 08 Jul 2022 | Sam Woods | Sam Woods: Solvency II - striking the balance | Speech (virtual) by Mr Sam Woods , Deputy Governor for Prudential Regulation of the Bank of England and Chief Executive of the Prudential Regulation Authority (PRA), at the Bank of England Webinar, 8 July 2022. by Sam Woods |
| 08 Jul 2022 | Pablo Hernández de Cos | Pablo Hernández de Cos: 1st Bank of Spain conference on the Spanish economy | Welcome address by Mr Pablo Hernández de Cos, Governor of the Bank of Spain, at the 1st Bank of Spain Conference on the Spanish Economy, Madrid, 7 July 2022. by Pablo Hernández de Cos |
| 08 Jul 2022 | Mário Centeno | Mário Centeno: Keynote intervention - 26th Economist Government Roundtable | Keynote intervention (virtual) by Mr Mário Centeno, Governor of the Banco de Portugal, at the 26th Economist Government Roundtable, 7 July 2022. by Mário Centeno |
| 08 Jul 2022 | Pan Gongsheng | Pan Gongsheng: Speech - Fifth Anniversary Forum of Bond Connect and the launch ceremony of Swap Connect | Speech (virtual) by Mr Pan Gongsheng, Deputy Governor of the People's Bank of China, at the Fifth Anniversary Forum of Bond Connect and the Launch Ceremony of Swap Connect, 4 July 2022. by Pan Gongsheng |

Comment: thanks a lot! Two great answers! Life saving. I awarded the first one just because the second one on "text" gets the "wrong" code. But 2 great answers. Thanks a lot again